# Https Domain Redirection Guide

Tags: apache, nginx, server, dns

I am facing an issue with the domain redirection.

I am trying to redirect my old domain to another new one, so the current domain is for example https://example.com and the new one is https://exampleapple.com the old is using SSL and I implement SSL on the new too, the old domain redirects fine without SSL (http) but is not redirecting on (https).

Can anyone please guide me as how this works?

Comment: Can you share the config that you have tried?

Comment: I am hosting the site on my dedicated server and using VestaCP, i simply redirect the domain from Godaddy as permanent redirect, Can you be specific as what config do you need?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that with .htaccess file. There is no need to use GoDaddy's functionality. Just add these lines to the .htaccess file in the directory of your example.com domain on your server :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/exampleapple\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ralitsa, will this completely redirect the domain? i mean i have never done this, Wont i need any redirection from Godaddy panel? because first i will point the new domain to my Server IP and then i redirect the old domain to the new one.

Comment: Guys? can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Yes, this will redirect any requets to your old domain name to the new one with httpS. Meaning that if anyone tries to open with/without www   , or with/without https they will end up at https://exampleapple.com. And no , there is no need for you to do anything at Godaddy, you should just add example.com to your server , point it to your server and then use the above . htaccess in the home directory of example.com and everything will work.

Comment: You are not getting me, I have one server which has domain example.com and i want to implement a new domain on this server exampleapple.com, there is no new server, I want to permanently redirect the old domain once i implement the new one.